# Roboframework set variable for RCC command line

Tags: robotframework

The documentation indicates we should be able to change Scalar variables in .robot files when we execute a robot with the command line https://robocorp.com/docs/languages-and-frameworks/robot-framework/variables with the option --variable https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line

But every attempt like this `rcc run --variable MYVARIABLE:value` result with this error `Error: [rcc v11.4.3] unknown flag: --variable`

How can we define différents variables each time we wan't to execute the robot ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like variables for RCC have been disabled/removed or not implemented.
The answer --> https://forum.robocorp.com/t/how-to-pass-variables-when-running-rcc/1209

On linux,  environment variables have to be used, for example: `MYVARIABLE="123" rcc run`